# Какой тип указывается для флагов в сигнатуре функции для PHP?

Tags: php, функции, документация

На [странице](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-change-key-case.php) функции array_change_key_case в документации PHP указана такая сигнатура:

```
array_change_key_case(array $array, int $case = CASE_LOWER): array
```

В ней всё понятно, кроме int перед $case. Почему его тип указан как int? Внешне доступные флаги на число не похожи:

- CASE_LOWER
- CASE_UPPER

Нужно ли указывать int как тип для флагов всегда или это от чего-то зависит?
Если он указывается всегда, то известна ли причина этого или это традиция?
Или может быть это опечатка и у флагов должен быть указан другой тип?

Comment: CASE_LOWER и CASE_UPPER это самые обычные константы самого обычного типа int

Comment: В документации не написаны их значения, но через банальный echo можно увидеть, что они равны 0 и 1 соответственно

Comment: @andreymal
Как можно использовать echo на подобной константе?

Comment: Да как обычно просто `echo CASE_LOWER;` да и всё, ну или ещё `var_dump(CASE_LOWER);` заодно и название типа выведет

Comment: @andreymal спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оказалось, что предопределенные флаги, которые используются в функциях - это обычные константы (только определяются они не в коде, а в исходниках РНР). И к ним можно обратиться так же, как к обычным константам - через echo, var_dump, print_r и пр.
Плюс можно посмотреть их всех через get_defined_constants(). CASE_LOWER и CASE_UPPER из примера тоже там будут.

Поэтому, отвечая на вопрос прямо:

- Нужно ли указывать int как тип для флагов всегда или это от чего-то зависит?
- Тип константы, которая используются в виде флага, зависит от её предназначения, и поэтому он может отличаться в зависимости от функции и необязательно будет int. Посмотреть тип той или иной константы можно с помощью var_dump(константа).

После ответа на основной вопрос, остальные теряют актуальность.